# processing multiple certificate requests

Tags: batch-file

I have several thousand certificate requests to process to our corporate certificate authority server, and I would like to generate all the certificates in a batch.  reading the .csr file from a directory, running this command

```
Certreq -submit -config CAserver\orgca -attrib "CertificateTemplate:Enterpriseprinter" certificaterequest.csr certificatename.cer
```

against each csr file to generate and download the certs into a directory.  How can I sequentially process each .csr file using a batch or script?

I'm pretty new to scripting.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: A for loop is probably the way to go. Type for /? at a command prompt.